# Pythonic way to get value of first XML element with specific name

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am looking for a better way to write this tiny piece of code:

```
  uris = []
            for el in tree.iter('uri'):
                uris.append(el.text)
                break
            self.phoneLine = uris[0]
```

Since I can not use this:

```
value = tree.iter('uri')[0].text
```

Comment: `tree.find('uri').text`?

Comment: `for el in tree.iter('uri'):
            self.phoneLine = el.text
            break
` Nah use what @Rakesh said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might use:

```
self.phoneLine = next(tree.iter('uri')).text
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if your XML-Tree only has one `uri`  element , or you want only to get the first element:

```
self.phoneline = tree.find('uri').text
```

Edit: Works only if `uri` element is a direkt child of your tree element.

Comment: This only works if the `uri` node is a direct child of the root.